# I think I found a pattern in limits approaching infinity.

Tags: limits

Can it be assumed that limits approaching $\infty$ or $-\infty$ can be found by taking the coefficient of the infinity multiplied by the coefficient of the highest power in the numerator divided by the coefficent of the highest power in the denominator? For example:
$$\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{5x^2-2}}{x+3} = -\sqrt5$$
The process I used was simply $\dfrac {\sqrt5}{1} \times-1$, and it seems to work for every problem on my homework assignment. I'm just looking for clarification that this either works or doesn't work every time, since it is a lot faster than actually figuring through the problem.

Comment: Try $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{5x+2}{6x^2-x}, \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{5x+4}{8x-7}, \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{6x^2 + 2^x}}{2x+5}$. Check their graphs to see if your answers match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something to this, though it's not quite so simple, and there are limits that don't fall into this pattern.  To state it properly, you want to do something like this.
Suppose you're trying to find

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{F(x)}{G(x)}$$
and you can write
$$ \eqalign{F(x) &= h(x) f(x)\cr
            G(x) &= h(x) g(x)}$$
where $G(x) \ne 0$ for large $x$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = a$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = b \ne 0$.  Then $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{F(x)}{G(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)}{\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)} = \frac{a}{b}$$

[EDIT]
For example, consider your
$$ \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{5 x^2 - 2}}{x+3}$$
Thus $F(x) = \sqrt{5 x^2 - 2}$ and $G(x) = x+3$.  We take $h(x) = x$ so
$$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{5 x^2 - 2}}{x} = \text{(if $x < 0$)} -\sqrt{5 - 2/x^2}$$ and $$g(x) = \frac{x+3}x = 1 + \frac{3}{x}$$
Expressed this way, it's easy to see that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -\sqrt{5}$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} g(x) = 1$, so the answer is $-\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the statement "and you can write F(x)G(x)=h(x)f(x)=h(x)g(x)"? Also, is it possible that you could PM me a numerical example so I can try to work through what you're saying?

Comment: @CoolDoodShooz1 Prof. Israel is referring to how the numerator ($F$) and denominator ($G$) functions in your limited quotient ($\lim\frac{F}{G}$) might both be expressible in terms of -- what we might loosely call -- a "coefficient part" ($f$, $g$ respectively) and an "order part" ($h$). The order of a function is how fast it grows, essentially like its highest polynomial power (e.g. $x^2$ for quadratics or $x^3$ for cubics) but more generally applicable than just for polynomials. (1/2)

Comment: So this is assuming that $h(x) =$ the reciprocal of the highest power, correct?

Comment: Say, for example, we are to find $\lim \frac{F}{G}$, where $F(x) = \color{red}{5}\cdot \color{blue}{x^3}$ and $G(x) = \color{red}{\left(3+1/x\right)} \cdot \color{blue}{\left(x^6+1\right)^{1/2} }$. Then both $F$ and $G$ are products of a term tending to a constant (which I've marked in red) and a term asymptotic to $x^3$ (in blue), which is to say, for sufficiently large $x$, it grows like $x^3$. Then, in this case, we can "cancel out" the blue terms, and we have $\lim \frac{F}{G} = \lim \frac{\color{red}{f}\,\color{blue}{(\sim x^3)}}{\color{red}{g}\,\color{blue}{(\sim x^3)}}=\frac53$. (2/2)